# How do I make AFHTTP request wait for operation

Tags: afnetworking

At this moment I have a method that calls for the download of data from the web using AFHTTPRequestOperation like so:

```
- (void)downloadDataForRegisteredObjects:(BOOL)useUpdatedAtDate {
    NSLog(@"downloadDataForRegisteredObjects");
    NSMutableArray *operations = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *className in self.registeredClassesToSync) {
        NSDate *mostRecentUpdatedDate = nil;
        if (useUpdatedAtDate) {
            mostRecentUpdatedDate = [self mostRecentUpdatedAtDateForEntityWithName:className]; 
        }
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[SDAFParseAPIClient sharedClient] GETRequestForAllRecordsOfClass:className updatedAfterDate:mostRecentUpdatedDate];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[SDAFParseAPIClient sharedClient] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                // Write JSON files to disk
                [self writeJSONResponse:responseObject toDiskForClassWithName:className];
            }
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Request for class %@ failed with error: %@", className, error);
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
             postNotificationName:kSDSyncEngineSyncINCompleteNotificationName
             object:nil];

        }];

        [operations addObject:operation];
    }

    [[SDAFParseAPIClient sharedClient] enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:operations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfCompletedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {

    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
        // Process JSON into CD
        if (useUpdatedAtDate) { 
            [self processJSONDataRecordsIntoCoreData]; 
        }

    }];
}
```

From what I understand, we create an NSURLMutableRequest, pass it to an AFHTTPRequestOperation with a success & failure block.

The success block says, if and when successful, test if dictionary and if so, write it to disk.  The failure block says, log the error and post a notification.

The method gets called twice in my app, in series, one after the other.  The first time it returns an empty responseObject but the second time it returns a full responseObject.

Why should that be the case?